# Как избежать дублирования методов в Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Работая над одним проектом(сам новичок) столкнулся со следующей дилеммой:

Допустим у меня есть такой метод:

```
methods:{
  rquire_img(img){
    return require('~static/img/' + img);
  }   
 }
```

Этот метод мне приходиться вызывать чуть ли не в каждом модуле.
  Возникает желание вынести как то этот метод отдельно и подключать(если это возможно) в каждый компонент.

Вопрос:
Как это сделать правильнее всего с точки зрения семантики ну и вообще проектирования проекта?
(+ что бы реактивность состояний при этом так же сохранялась на прежнем уровне у этого подключаемого метода.)

И главное как потом навешивать эти подключения метода на разные теги?
Имею виду подключение через:

```
:src="require_img(бла..бла..бла..)"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через [примесь(mixin)](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) или добавить эту функцию в файл с хелперами, оттуда импортировать и вставлять в methods.

**helpers.js**:

```
export function rquire_img (img)
  return require('~static/img/' + img);
}
```

**В компоненте**:

```
import { rquire_img } from '../helpers'
```

В методах:

```
methods: {
   rquire_img, // сокращение от rquire_img: rquire_img 
   ...
}
```

Comment: А файл с хелперами уже где то есть по дефолту в Nuxt.js или это вы имеете ввиду просто обычный файл создать?
(впервые слышу честно говоря о таком файле.)

Comment: Для таких элементарных вещей nuxt не нужен, просто можете создать файл в корне проекта, я такой чуть ли не в каждом проекте делаю.